# Windows 7: Automatic Logon Policy not working for winhttp API VB6 activeX control

Tags: vb6, windows-7, activex, windows-authentication, winhttprequest

I'm using WinHttp to do POSTs in a VB6 activeX control as follows

```
Set WinHttpReq = New WinHttpRequest
WinHttpReq.Open "POST", strUrl, False
WinHttpReq.SetAutoLogonPolicy AutoLogonPolicy_Always
aPostBody = 'Sometext'
WinHttpReq.Send aPostBody
UploadFile = WinHttpReq.ResponseText
```

This works great on windows XP (all versions of IE), but on windows 7 it sends back a 401 and Automatic Logon Policy doesn't work here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383144(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some more on the VB6 activeX control, I implemented the control in C# using

[Code Project : Downloading C# ActiveX Components through CAB File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Deployment.aspx)

Works like a charm, no more authentication issues rather now I can do so much more since it's good old C#.